# Programming philosophy when dealing with base cases

Tags: algorithm

I was tinkering around with a function that tests for intersections between rectangles and circles and the original function I had had four cases to test against. In order they were:

1.) If the bounding rectangle of the circle doesn't intersect the rectangle, return False

2.) If any of the points of the rectangle lie in the circle, return True

3.) If the center of the circle lies in the rectangle, return True

4.) Iterate through the lines in the rectangle and test for intersections with the circle individually. If there are any intersections, break and return True.

But upon timing the function with `timeit`, I realized that it was actually faster on average to omit cases 1-3 and just purely use 4 to test for collisions (on average it was a 100% increase in speed, it was twice as fast for 1000 tests).

I originally implemented all four cases because the more common cases (1 - 3) would terminate the function quickly if they returned True but I guess I thought wrong. So my question is, what is your guys' philosophy when it comes to programming and accounting for different scenarios? Do you try to implement one algorithm that works all the time, or three or four algorithms that each individually cost much less than the lone algorithm?

Here is the code in case you wanted to look at it, it's kind of useless since it relies on other things I've made but you'll probably be able to get an idea of what's going on:

```
    def collide_rect(self, rect):
        """Check if the circle collides with a rect."""
##        if not rect.collide_rect(self.to_rect()):
##            # Case 1 ~ The bounding rects don't intersect.
##            return False
##        # Case 2 ~ One of the points on the rect is inside the circle.
##        points = rect.points()
##        if any(self.collide_point(v) for v in points):
##            return True
##        if rect.collide_point(self._center):
##            # Case 3 ~ The circle is entirely contained by the rect.
##            return True
        # Case 4 ~ None of the points from the rect fall inside
        # the circle. Now we must check if any of the lines from
        # the rect intersect the boundaries of the circle. To do
        # this, we know that if a line intersects a circle's boundary,
        # then there exists some value `t` such that 0 <= `t` <= 1
        # (i.e. `t` is a ratio), and the distance from the point at
        # ratio `t` on the line segment is also the radius of the circle.
        points = rect.points()
        _abs = abs
        for i in range(4):
            start = points[i - 1]
            end = points[i]
            _line = Segment(start, end)
            if _line.isHorizontal():
                if (_line._s.x < self.x < _line._e.x) or \
                   (_line._s.x > self.x > _line._e.x)    :
                    if _abs(_line._s.y - self.y) <= self.r:
                        return True
                else:
                    dist1 = (_line._s.x - self.x)**2 + (_line._s.y - self.y)**2
                    dist2 = (_line._e.x - self.x)**2 + (_line._e.y - self.y)**2
                    if dist1 <= self.r**2 or dist2 <= self.r**2:
                        return True
            elif _line.isVertical():
                if (_line._s.y < self.y < _line._e.y) or \
                   (_line._s.y > self.y > _line._e.y)    :
                    if _abs(_line._s.x - self.x) <= self.r:
                        return True
                else:
                    dist1 = (_line._s.x - self.x)**2 + (_line._s.y - self.y)**2
                    dist2 = (_line._e.x - self.x)**2 + (_line._e.y - self.y)**2
                    if dist1 <= self.r**2 or dist2 <= self.r**2:
                        return True
        return False
```

(The commented out parts of the code are the cases 1-3 removed).

Comment: Does your testcases cover every possibility? For instance, if you used bad test data, only step 4 would actually be used.

Comment: Also note that whether to keep those steps would probably depend on whether most of your circles would not intersect with the square or if most would. Ie. what is the most common occurance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is: is the last algorithm fast enough for you? If you don't have any performance problem, you don't have to worry with other cases.

One case only means less code, so less bugs and easier maintenance.

As it is often said in computer science, premature optimization is the root of all evil ;)
So start with mesuring the performances, and if they aren't good enough *because of the collision detection*, optimize by adding one of the other  tests. Then iterate :)